# Fprintf is not printing data to the file

Tags: c

I am trying to get the data in my arr array to print to the file "out.txt". The program was able to do it before but for some reason will now not print at all and even after undoing to a previous version nothing will print.

I have code in place that proves both that the File is successfully opened and the data is correct in the array. All other functions work properly.

```
int main () {

    FILE *inFile;
    FILE *outFile;
    int n = 0;

    inFile = fopen("in.txt", "r");

    if (inFile == NULL) {
        printf("File failed to open");
    }
    outFile = fopen("out.txt", "w");

    if (outFile == NULL) {
        printf("outFile failed to open");
    }

    fscanf(inFile, "%d", &n);

    struct Point* arr;
    arr = (struct Point*) malloc (n * sizeof(struct Point));
    int i = 0;


    while (i<n){
        fscanf(inFile, "%d %d", &arr[i].x, &arr[i].y);
        i++;
    }

    mergeSort(arr, 0, n-1);

    fprintf(outFile, "%d\n", n);

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%d %d\n", arr[i].x, arr[i].y);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        fprintf(outFile, "%d %d\n", arr[i].x, arr[i].y);
    }

    printf("\nSorted and output written to File\n");

    int searchx, searchy;

    printf("Please enter a point to search for:  ");
    scanf("%d %d", &searchx, &searchy);

    int result = 0;

    result = binarySearch(arr, searchx, searchy,0, n);

    if (result == -1) {
        printf("Point not found");
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        printf("Point found in element %d", result);
    }
    fclose(inFile);
    fclose(outFile);
}
```

expected results with sample input.
In.txt:

```
5
6 3
4 6
2 5
2 7
5 2
```

out.txt:

```
5
2 5
2 7
4 6
5 2
6 3
```

Actual results:
out.txt:

```
//Blank
```

Comment: Is that the whole code? Where are you trying to read it? Do you close the file before that?

Comment: Edited to add the full main function, i only close the files at the very end and both txt files open successfully

Comment: All other functions work properly, the arr is sorted correctly and the outFile pointer doesn't equal NULL. The only portions of the code that seem to not work are the 

fprintf(outFile, "%d\n", n);    And     


for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
    fprintf(outFile, "%d %d\n", arr[i].x, arr[i].y);
}

Comment: Make a [mcve]. Substitute `outFile` with `stdout` and run your program with a debugger. Execute a line at a time and check on the console.

Comment: All of the scanfs work, when i print the array to the console it prints fine. Its only the fprintfs that arent working.

Answer (score 0):

That code runs fine here on my Mac, at least with the mergeSort commented out. You're not running on Windows, are you? If so the file may look empty because it's missing carriage returns.

Comment: Ok seriously starting to think its an issue with my compiler, just tried it with my mergeSort commented out and it didn't work

Comment: Has the program terminated on your system? Maybe the data just isn't getting flushed out. Try closing the file?

Comment: Just restarted my entire comp, still nothing

Comment: Yah i am on windows, whats carriage returns?

Comment: @Robertf pursuit of carriage returns is pointless for this exercise. You're (hopefully) writing data. Checking the result of the `fprintf` to ensure its actually writing the data would probably be a worthy endeavor. And check your CWD (though I expect it is valid, otherwise `in.txt` wouldn't be opening either unless the one you're opening isn't the one you think it is). Are you running this in some IDE (like Visual Studio, where the CWD at debug-time is the same folder as the *project* file by default?)

Comment: I am running this in code blocks. The only issue is that this code was working fine about 2 hours ago. I stepped away and came back to it after an hour of rest to test it more and it all of a sudden wasn't working.